# Setting up a mail server best practices to be recognized as legitimate

Tags: configuration, email-server

What are the best practices to configure a mail server to have your mail recognized as legitimate non spam messages? Is it to use Domain Keys, Sender ID, Sender Policy Framework, some or all 3 of these together?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few similar mail related questions on SF already, however I'll answer this one as best I can. To avoid being recognised as spam, check:

- [You're not on a blacklist](http://www.spamhaus.org/lookup.lasso)
- Your server has [MX and reverse DNS records](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/)
- You have [SPF DNS records](http://antone.geckotribe.com/alpha-gecko/how-to-set-up-spf-records/) (many servers reject mail without a valid SPF, GMail for example, here's [an explanation](http://www.ipswitch.com/support/ics/guides/IMailServer/8_2/IMailUGHTML/Chapter%202%20config12.html) and [a wizard](http://old.openspf.org/wizard.html))
- Your mailserver's [HELO response matches your hostname](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/postfix-HELO.html)
- Your mailserver is [not an open relay](http://www.spamhelp.org/shopenrelay/)
- Your [DNS records' TTL](http://www.simpledns.com/help/v51/index.html?df_ttl.htm) is not too low - 86400 (24 hours) is recommended (some spammers set their TTL very low to regularly update forged DNS records)

I have never required [Sender ID](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_vs_Sender_ID), although as it's a Microsoft protocol I'd assume it's more important for Exchange/Live based mail - I have never had problems in this department without implementing Sender ID.

Comment: This was exactly the type of answer I was looking for, thanks Andy!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that disabling open SMTP relay, and having valid reverse DNS entries, is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Also don't send spam through it. :)